# Problems deserializing List of objects

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am having trouble deserializing a list of objects. I can get just one object to serialize into an object but cannot get the list.  I get no error it just returns an empty List. This is the XML that gets returned:

```
<locations>
   <location locationtype="building" locationtypeid="1">
     <id>1</id>
     <name>Building Name</name>
     <description>Description of Building</description>
   </location>
</locations>
```

This is the class I have and I am deserializing in the `GetAll` method:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("location")]
public class Building
{
    private string method;

    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("mubuildingid")]
    public string MUBuildingID { get; set; }

    public List<Building> GetAll()
    {
        var listBuildings = new List<Building>();
        var building = new Building();
        var request = WebRequest.Create(method) as HttpWebRequest;
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        TextReader reader = streamReader;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Building>), 
            new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = "locations" });
        listBuildings = (List<Building>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        return listBuildings;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error are you getting?

Comment: What list are you not seeing serialized?  If it's the `GetAll()` method, it's because serializers are not (well, possibly rarely, I guess) in the business of invoking class methods.  They are in the business of preserving an object's property values.

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it is just returning an empty list.  I am not trying to Serialize the GetAll Method, i am using the Get All Method to deserialize from a webservice and fill that building object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
[XmlRoot("locations")]
public class BuildingList
{
    public BuildingList() {Items = new List<Building>();}
    [XmlElement("location")]
    public List<Building> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Then deserialize the whole BuildingList object.

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BuildingList));
var list = (BuildingList)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xml);
```

Comment: FYI, if you need to deserialize the attributes (e.g. `locationtype` etc) that is possible also by decorating the corresponding property with `XmlAttribute`.

Comment: Error 4 Attribute 'XmlElement' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field, param, return' declarations.

Comment: Did this work for you? I tested the code and it was able to correctly deserialize a list of several locations. You can just return `list.Items` to get just the `List<Locations>`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old(er) question, but I struggled with this today, and found an answer that doesn't require encapsulation.

**Assumption 1:** You have control over the source Xml and how it is constructed.

**Assumption 2:** You are trying to serialise the Xml directly into a `List<T>` object

1. You must name the Root element in the Xml as `ArrayOfxxx` where xxx is the name of your class (or the name specified in XmlType (see 2.))
2. If you wish your xml Elements to have a different name to the class, you should use `XmlType` on the class.

**NB:** If your Type name (or class name) starts with a lowercase letter, you should convert the first character to uppercase.

**Example 1 - Without `XmlType`**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //String containing the xml array of items.
        string xml =
@"<ArrayOfItem>
    <Item>
        <Name>John Doe</Name>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Martha Stewart</Name>
    </Item>
</ArrayOfItem>";


        List<Item> items = null;
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml)))
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(mem))
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Item>)); //Deserialising to List<Item>
            items = (List<Item>)ser.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        if (items != null)
        {
            items.ForEach(I => Console.WriteLine(I.Name));
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No Items Deserialised");

    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Example 2 - With `XmlType`**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //String containing the xml array of items.
        //Note the Array Name, and the Title case on stq.
        string xml =
@"<ArrayOfStq>
    <stq>
        <Name>John Doe</Name>
    </stq>
    <stq>
        <Name>Martha Stewart</Name>
    </stq>
</ArrayOfStq>";


        List<Item> items = null;
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml)))
        using (var stream = new StreamReader(mem))
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Item>)); //Deserialising to List<Item>
            items = (List<Item>)ser.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        if (items != null)
        {
            items.ForEach(I => Console.WriteLine(I.Name));
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No Items Deserialised");

    }
}

[XmlType("stq")]
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how Building corresponds with the location you have in your xml, but to me it makes more sense if they're named equivalently. Instead of using a List use a LocationList, and it becomes:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("locations")]
public class LocationCollection{
    [XmlElement("location")]
    public Location[] Locations {get;set;}
}

[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("location")]
public class Location
{    
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("locationtype")]
    public string LocationType {get;set;}
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("mubuildingid")]
    public string MUBuildingID { get; set; }    
}
```

You can then deserialize as follows:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(method) as HttpWebRequest;
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
TextReader reader = streamReader;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LocationCollection), 
   new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = "locations" });
var listBuildings = (LocationCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

return listBuildings;
```

Comment: Building is just one type of LocationType and this specific application just needs buildings, so it has a building object it is using int he application which will populate through the webservice.  I was trying to stay away from creating another class just for Collections since returning it in a method or in a static method inside the object kept everything localized in the object.

Comment: IMHO, a DTO calling a web service internally seems like a really bad idea to me. Also, you can still keep the LocationCollection internal and then just return listBuildings.Locations, which is Location[]

Comment: How is this different from what I posted? You only switched from a List<T> to an array, and the OP requested a List<T>

Comment: The array part of this answer helped me since the javascript deserializer I was using could not create lists

Answer (score 0):

I know, old question, but came across it when faced by a similar issue.
Building on @ricovox's answer and in context of the OP's question, this is the model I would use to serialize his xml:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("locations")]
public class BuildingList
{
    [XmlArrayItem("location", typeof(Building))]
    public List<Building> locations { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Building
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MUBuildingID { get; set; }

    public List<Building> GetAll()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The OP's mistake was to create the list item as the root

Answer (score -1):

Use  [XMLArray] for collection properties.