# Reading data from XML file and putting in List. What is the issue?

Tags: c#, xml, list

I have a problem with C# deserializer method for reading data from XML and putting it into List<>. I Have following XML File:
events.xml

```
<ArrayOfEvent xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Event>
  <eventID>0</eventID>
  <type>Theatre</type>
  <title>City of gods</title>
  <price>100</price>
  <city>London</city>
  <place>Culture hall</place>
  <date>2014-12-18T20:00:00</date>
  <available_tickets>500</available_tickets>
  <reserved_tickets>0</reserved_tickets>
</Event>

<Event>
  <eventID>1</eventID>
  <type>Concert</type>
  <title>Jon Hopkins</title>
  <price>500</price>
  <city>Radbroke</city>
  <place>Arena</place>
  <date>2014-12-18T20:00:00</date>
  <available_tickets>200</available_tickets>
  <reserved_tickets>0</reserved_tickets>
</Event>
</ArrayOfEvent>
```

Event.cs

```
public class Event
    {
        public int eventID { get; set; }
        public String type { get; set; }
        public String title { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public String city { get; set; }
        public String place { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public String description { get; set; }
        public int available_tickets { get; set; }
        public int reserved_tickets { get; set; }

        public Event(){}
        public Event(int ID, String typ, String titl, double pric, String cit, String plac, DateTime dat, String descriptio, int available_t, int reserved_t ){
            eventID = ID;
            type = typ;
            title = titl;
            price = pric;
            city = cit;
            place = plac;
            date = dat;
            description = descriptio;
            available_tickets = available_t;
            reserved_tickets = reserved_t;

        }
```

Database.cs

```
public List<Event> loadEvents() {
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Event>));
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader("events.xml");
            events = (List<Event>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            textReader.Close();
            return events;
        }
```

EventAdd.cs

```
Database data = new Database();

  public void testEvents(List<Event>){
    data.loadEvents();
    Console.WriteLine(events.Count.ToString()); 
  }
```

> Output: 0

The problem is that it prints 0; 
I cant even perform any actions with that readed list because it is empty.
Please help me, i am suffering from this issue for days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367168/problems-deserializing-list-of-objects

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you provided class Event, Everything looks OK if you have "< /ArrayOfEvent >" in your xml correctly.

I tested in my PC using the following code

```
string xml = "<ArrayOfEvent xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
    @"<Event>
    <eventID>0</eventID>
    <type>Theatre</type>
    <title>City of gods</title>
    <price>100</price>
    <city>London</city>
    <place>Culture hall</place>
    <date>2014-12-18T20:00:00</date>
    <available_tickets>500</available_tickets>
    <reserved_tickets>0</reserved_tickets>
    </Event>
    </ArrayOfEvent>";

List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Event>));
TextReader textReader = new StringReader(xml);
events = (List<Event>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
textReader.Close();
Console.WriteLine(events.Count);
```

the code is similar to yours, but use StringReader() instead of load from a file.

```
the output is 1.
```

so the problem should be your xml file.
maybe in a incorrect path, maybe contains some extra bytes such as BOM, maybe the encoding problem.
you need to figure it out by yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for fast response.Sorry, i forgot to insert that piece of code. I did that. But the problem is not there. I will try to update question.

Comment: btw, i hope you have  </ArrayOfEvent> in your xml right? i will update my answer too

Comment: 1) the path is correct, because with the same path i fill the xml file.2) `public static void saveEvents(List<Event> events)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Event>));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("events.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, events);
            textWriter.Close();
        }`

Comment: Eh.. but my code works right? Maybe you should try StringReader + File.ReadAllText() to help debuging.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN sample,
`[XmlElement(Namespace = "")]` is to be included before every member of the class. Try adding this to your code.

The [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he66c7f1(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN is this.

```
public class OrderedItem
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public string ItemName;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public string Description;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cohowinery.com")]
    public decimal UnitPrice;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public int Quantity;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cohowinery.com")]
    public decimal LineTotal;
    // A custom method used to calculate price per item. 
    public void Calculate()
    {
        LineTotal = UnitPrice * Quantity;
    }
}
```